# How do I find the common difference if the first term is unknown?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Given the formula: $A_n = A_1+ (n-1)d$

I'm trying to look for $d$, if given the the second and $17^{\text{th}} $ terms, namely $37$ and $82$.

I can't seem to figure out where to start; if $A_1$ were at least given I might have a starting point, but here I'm  completely lost now that both are missing.

Comment: Find $A(17)-A(2)$ which should be a computable multiple of $d.$

Comment: How many terms are there from $A_2$ to $A_{17}$?

Comment: @KM101 Starting at $A(2),$ the common difference $d$ should be added $15$ times to get $A(17.)

Comment: @coffeemath For $n$ terms, the difference is added $(n-1)$ times, I know. This is equivalent to finding $d$ given the first and sixteenth terms.

Comment: Then how many d added from second to seventeenth?

Comment: $16$ terms from $A_2$ to $A_{17}$ means $d$ is added $15$ times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$a_{17} - a_2 = 45 = 16d - d = 15d$$

Comment: A(17) - A(2) = A(15)  -> ( *A(17) - *A(2) ) / 15 = 3 = d. Giving an A(1) of 34. I got it solved shortly after posting. I think I got thrown off by online texts saying A starts at A(0) as opposed to my A(1) start. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The $n$th term of an arithmetic sequence is

$$a+(n-1)d$$
where $a$ is the first term and $d$ is the common difference between each term.

You have:

$$a+16d=82\tag1$$
$$a+d=37\tag2$$
When we perform $(1)-(2)$, what do we get?